# PowerShell mailbox filtering bug?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Checking if a certain address is already in use by any mailbox as SMTP or SIP address.

The below command doesn't automatically search for SIP addresses without adding the prefix so:

- $SMTP = "bruce@###.com"
- $SIP = "sip:bruce@###.com"

  ```
  Get-Mailbox -Filter 'emailaddresses -eq $SMTP -or emailaddresses -eq "sip:bruce@###.com"'
  ```

The above works, the below doesn't:

```
   Get-Mailbox -Filter 'emailaddresses -eq $SMTP -or emailaddresses -eq $SIP'
```

Tried ToString() and a bunch of other things but I can't get it to work with the variable, not sure what the problem is here... both variables are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[doc.mircosoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6):

> When you enclose a string in single-quotation marks (a single-quoted string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed.

So the filter:

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter 'emailaddresses -eq $SMTP -or emailaddresses -eq $SIP'
```

will be used as it is (`'emailaddresses -eq $SMTP -or emailaddresses -eq $SIP'`) no variable substitution will be done.

Change it to:

```
 Get-Mailbox -Filter "emailaddresses -eq $SMTP -or emailaddresses -eq $SIP"
```

and

```
 Get-Mailbox -Filter "emailaddresses -eq $SMTP -or emailaddresses -eq `"sip:bruce@###.com`""
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Get-Mailbox -Filter "emailaddresses -eq '$SMTP' -or emailaddresses -eq '$SIP'"